# Exception occurs in Windows .Net Application because of version mismatch on DLL

Tags: .net, windows, dll

I have a Windows Service application that I can also run as a Windows Form application for testing purposes. There are several dlls that are linked to my main project. Only one is causing me a problem. The inner exception gives me a clue that something is wrong. Here it is:

> {"Could not load file or assembly 'HIDDProcessing, Version=1.0.5191.17319, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=863435ae869eb242' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)":"HIDDProcessing, Version=1.0.5191.17319, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=863435ae869eb242"}
>
> System.IO.FileLoadException: {"Could not load file or assembly 'HIDDProcessing, Version=1.0.5191.17319, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=863435ae869eb242' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)":"HIDDProcessing, Version=1.0.5191.17319, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=863435ae869eb242"}

I can solve this by deleting the hiddprocessing.dll’s and recompiling. However I’m wondering why I have to do this. None of the other dll’s are causing me any problems.

I have noticed that if I do to the reference list all the other dll have a fixed version number. For example 1.0.0.0. While my problem dll has a specific version, for example 1.0.5190.26584. If I could get rid of the specific version, I think my problem would go away. But I don’t know how to do it.

Comment: You simply copied a DLL that has the wrong version.  It is not version 1.0.5191.17319.  With version numbers like that, this is rarely a great surprise.  Whomever created that assembly is taking a shortcut on version numbering, he's using automatic version number incrementing.  Him simply rebuilding the DLL without otherwise making *any* changes to the code produces another version.  That's a pretty crappy way to version software but not uncommon, a build server tends to make that less of a problem.  Recompiling with the updated assembly as a reference is required to avoid the runtime error.

Comment: Thanks for responding Hans. I'm not sure what you are suggesting. How to I change the code to get rid of the specific version? Am I changing the DLL or my main executable? Please be specific.

Comment: No idea how much more specific I need to be, the last sentence was quite explicit and did not say to change code.

Comment: Just recompiling doesn't work. If I delete the dll and then recompile then it works. I don't want to have to do that.